# Getting java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer when retrieving value from SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, classcastexception

I am trying to use SharedPreferences to store some values and retrieve them when the app opens, but I have issues with retrieving some int values.

I have tried converting the value to a string and then using Integer.ParseInt to retrieve the value, but I still get an error.

**This is where my value should be stored:**

```
void putP1Index(int index) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
    mEditor.putInt(keyP1Index, index);
    mEditor.apply();
}

void putP2Index(int index) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
    mEditor.putInt(keyP2Index, index);
    mEditor.apply();
}
```

They are saved from a different class:

```
private MainGame mainGame;
private SavedValues savedValues;


ScoreSetter(MainGame mainGame) {
    this.mainGame = mainGame;
    savedValues = new SavedValues(mainGame);
}

void setScore(who) {
switch (who) {
        case 1:
            ++indexP1;
            savedValues.putP1Index(indexP1);
//Some code...
        case 2:
            ++indexP2;
            savedValues.putP2Index(indexP2);
//Some code...
}
}
```

**And I try to retrieve it like this:**

```
int getP1Index() {
    return mPrefs.getInt(keyP1Index, 0);
}

int getP2Index() {
    return mPrefs.getInt(keyP2Index, 0);
}
```

by calling them from a different class:

```
void getSavedValues() {
    indexP1 = savedValues.getP1Index();
    indexP2 = savedValues.getP2Index();
}
```

On the getSavedValues method I get the error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

What I don't understand is the fact that I save the value as int and try to retrieve them the same way.

Also, I have a similar method but with *booleans* and it works just fine.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-to-integer-in-java-parseint/

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same key to save your int as you are to retrieve it?  What are keyP1Index and keyP2Index at the time you save and retrieve your values?

Comment: Post the full code

Comment: @YasiruNayanajith Updated the code. Added what is relevant to this case as I have a lot of code that is irrelevant for this. As you can see, I am working only with integers and this is what baffles me.

Comment: Could it be that the value under the key `keyP1Index` or `keyP2Index` is a string written in a previous version of the app?

Comment: @wrock I think this may be it. I cleared the cache of the app and invalidated everything in Android Studio and the app opened.
I am testing now to see if everything works properly, but I think that the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue. There was nothing wrong with the code, but with a value that was written in a previous version of the app.

After cleaning the app data and and Invalidate and clear cache in Android Studio the issue disappeared.

Comment: Thanks! You saved my day! I had a similar problem in Flutter using the plugins 'permission_handler' and 'geolocator'. And the solution to this problem was also this Android Studio "feature".